# I need to mimic a ConcurrentDictionary with a normal Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, concurrency, thread-safety

Just as I said in the title I need to mimic a ConcurrentDictionary using Dictionaries because I need to serialize the said collection and the concurrent variant is not serializable. Any Idea in how ConcurrentDictionary handles multi-threading and how I should implement it?

I haven't tried it yet, i feel like a fish out of water.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. How are you serializing the collection? Posting a chunk of code with what you are trying to do as well as the error you are encountering would go a long way. As posted, your question is leading to a particular answer where there may be other approaches that solve your problem.

Comment: By the way, the source code for `ConcurrentDictionary` is [available online](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs).

Comment: I'd have thought sticking with the type designed for concurrent use and then customizing the serialization process would be more sensible than trying to rebuild the behaviour of the type.

Comment: Is it an option to just copy the `ConcurrentDictionary` to a new `Dictionary`, and serialize the copy? And do the reverse when you want to deserialize it.

Comment: @JuanR Hi, I tried using the BinaryFormatter, but I got an error that specified that ConcurrentDictionary is not marked as Serializable, so I did some research and found out that the ConcurrentDictionary can not be serialized. I thought about copying the content of the concurrentdictionaries into normal dictionaries and serializing them, but I need to do the serialization 10 times a second and on 12 different collections so that's not viable.

Comment: *"I need to do the serialization 10 times a second"* -- May I ask why you want to serialize the dictionary so frequently?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It is needed to keep track of a lot of entities in a 3d simulator to have a replay function

Comment: I think you should [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0011) and reconsider your serialization strategy.

Comment: What is the average/maximum size of the dictionaries that you want to serialize every 100 milliseconds? Just an estimation, not concrete numbers.

Comment: If only a few of the entries in the dictionary change from one iteration to the next, consider serializing and saving _just the changes_ on most iterations, and only occasionally saving the whole thing.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias there are like 12 concurrentDictionaries with max 15 object each with varing sizes from 10 to 110 properties, mostly numbers

Comment: How frequently are the dictionaries updated (keys added/modified/deleted)? Also regarding the objects that are stored as values in the dictionaries, are these mutable or immutable? If they are mutable, have you solved the thread-safety issues of mutating objects concurrently from multiple threads? The `ConcurrentDictionary` is only responsible for the thread-safety of its internal state, not for the thread-safety of the values it contains.

Comment: You could serialize the data as an array or list and re-create the dictionary when deserializing. The dictionary will have to be re-created anyway,

Comment: *"...to have a replay function."* -- Does the replay function needs to be persistent across program executions? If yes, how are you accomplishing this? Are you saving the serialized dictionaries in the disk every 100 milliseconds? Please consider editing the question and providing more information about your scenario.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, exactly, I found out that serializing into a json is doable, but returns a really big string and yes I need to save it to disk. The real problem now is the sheer size of the file, I tried keeping this up for maybe 30s and it gave me a 4MB file with the collections lightly populated. Realistically this should be running for 5 to 8 hours. Json serializing seems to be the way, but saving it raw on disk is not

Comment: I cringe in the thought of a program saving in the disk non-stop at full speed. Especially if the storage device is SSD, it's [life expectancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205064/batch-jobs-and-reduced-ssd-lifetime) might be shortened considerably.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`BinaryFormatter` serialization is [considered obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0011). Try using Json serialization instead:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Variant> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Variant>();
dict.TryAdd("one", new Variant() { Name = "one", Coordinate = new System.Drawing.Point() { } });
dict.TryAdd("two", new Variant() { Name = "two", Coordinate = new System.Drawing.Point() { } });    
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);

//This works just fine
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConcurrentDictionary<string, Variant>>(serialized);
```

You can then save this `string` in the storage of your choice.
Your data structures are not known so I just made something up for illustration purposes.

The one thing you will have to worry about is locking the serialization methods as you are attempting to do this several times per second. If you are saving it to disk, you are likely to run into file lock issues and what not. For this reason, you should reconsider your state saving strategy as well.

Something along the lines of:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Variant> _history = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Variant>();

//Somewhere in your code you populate the dictionary
_history.TryAdd("one", new Variant() { Name = "one", Coordinate = new System.Drawing.Point() { } });
_history.TryAdd("two", new Variant() { Name = "two", Coordinate = new System.Drawing.Point() { } });

private object _lock = new object();
private void SaveHistory()
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_history);
        DataLayer.SaveHistory(serialized);
    }                       
}

private void RestoreHistory()
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        var serialized = DataLayer.GetHistory();
        _history = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConcurrentDictionary<string, Variant>>(serialized);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "state saving strategy"?

Comment: @MrBott_a it looks to me like you are trying to serialize it so you can save some sort of state and then restore it. I modified my answer to illustrate a bit better.

Comment: Given the context of what the OP is storing, using a binary form of serialization is likely to be particularly important, and JSON is likely to be unacceptably slow and use an unacceptably large amount of disk space.

Comment: @Servy I tend to agree with you, except we don't really know much about the context or how he is storing it.

Comment: We know enough to know that this is almost certainly not the appropriate tool, given that we know there is a large amount of data that needs to be able to be serialized/deserialized quickly, and thus that the amount of bytes used to store the data is extremely important.  We don't necessarily know enough to know what the appropriate tool actually is, but it probably needs to be something pretty custom, given what little we do know.

Comment: @Servy I don't think that's accurate. He posted a comment. Take a look when you have a chance.

Comment: I've seen all of his comments at the time you posted yours.  I don't see anything that changes my impression thus far.

Comment: @Servy 180 objects sounds like a lot to serialize to you?

Comment: @JuanR When they each have dozens or hundreds of properties, and it's being written every frame for possibly a long period of time, potentially, yeah.  I'd be more worried about the file size of the replay than the ability of the disk to write that many bytes.  Soring all of that as JSON rather than storing the data as binary is going to be approximately an order of magnitude increase in bytes needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lock` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) to protect access to the `Dictionary` and ensure that only one thread at a time will do so. You can create an object to lock on, e.g.

```cs
private object syncRoot = new object();
```

and then lock on that:

```cs
lock (syncRoot)
{
    // Only one thread will be able to execute here at a time.
}
```

Comment: Why not lock the `Dictionary` object itself?

Comment: @arrowd From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices): `Use caution when locking on instances, for example lock(this) in C# or SyncLock(Me) in Visual Basic. If other code in your application, external to the type, takes a lock on the object, deadlocks could occur.` So long as you keep it private, you ar fine.

Comment: I fear that a lock may interfere with the performance a lot, ConcurrentDictionaries seem to do the same without locking...

Comment: @MrBott_a, they do no such thing. How do you think they provide the concurrency? They just have the lock code internal to the type so you don't have to write it yourself. Take a look at [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,2e5ef5704344a309) for the `ConcurrentDictionary` class.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I was under a wrong impression then, thanks, I will definetly look into that source code

Comment: @jmcilhinney If you look at your own link you can see that it's much more sophisticated than just locking on a single lock around normal dictionary operations.  It's able to omit locks in certain situations to improve performance, and it also has numerous locks, so that more localized locks can be used to allow actually concurrent access to the underlying data without lock contention in cases where it's valid to do so (i.e. when interacting with entirely separate buckets).

Answer (score 0):

Since the comments specified that this is for saving replays.

A better approach is probably to let the main thread, or whatever thread owns the data to be saved, create a copy of the data and put this in a buffer. This buffer can then either be kept in memory, or written out to disk concurrently with the game.

This way you avoid any risk of blocking the main game loop, and you are guaranteed to get consistent data. You could also add functions such as saving data ever n:th frame, or skipping data saving if the buffer is full.

The way I would implement this is with a [blockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-7.0) around a  [concurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-7.0). Create a long running task that loops over `myQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()`, and make sure to call `CompleteAdding` once done. But something like [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) might also be an option.

You should most likely also avoid BinaryFormatter, If speed is a concern I would probably use [Protobuf .net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net)  with the SerializeWithLengthPrefix methods, that way you can write out multiple independent objects to the same stream.

Comment: while this is almost certainly worth doing, it's wroth nothing that this doesn't change the fact that the work needs to be written as quickly as it comes in, at least on average over an extended period of time.  A buffer would let it get behind by a few frames and catch up later, but if the serialization is on average slower than the simulation itself the buffer will eventually fill up.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, I meant blockingCollection. I usually use them together, so I have kind of merged them in my mind.